# Script doesn't execute some code that has no if - clauses or similar

Tags: logging, groovy, syntax, jira

i wrote the following Code, which gave me the following output:

```
if(bodytoUpper.contains(currentfield)){
    int index = bodytoUpper.lastIndexOf(currentfield + "\n")//finds the last appearance of the field value
    log.debug("Index try if Abfrage: ")
    log.debug(index)
    int nextindex = bodytoUpper.lastIndexOf(nextfield, index)//finds the index of the next field
    log.debug("nextindex: ")
    log.debug(nextindex)
    value = currentbody.substring(index+currentfield.length(), nextindex);//sets the value to everything between the two indexes
    log.debug("Rückgabewert: ")
    log.debug(value)
}
```

The Output for that part is the following Log:

```
2017-12-22 11:24:52,853 DEBUG [acme.CreateSubtask]: Index try if Abfrage: 
2017-12-22 11:24:52,853 DEBUG [acme.CreateSubtask]: 18
```

The Problem is, that there are missing some logs, (and the code also won't be executed), but it doesn't output an error message.

Comment: What's the value of `nextfield`? Are there any exceptions in the log? (/are you swallowing exceptions?)

Comment: Nextfield is in this case the String "STATUS". I tested that it really is that. there are no exceptions in the log. replacing nextfield with "STATUS" also didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the aim of your script, but I guess it is to print everything between the last two appearances.

I think the problem is that you're searching backwards, so `nextindex` is BEFORE `index`. So you need to modify your code to something like this:

```
value = currentbody.substring(nextindex+currentfield.length(), index);
```

Comment: Why doesn't it log the line before, though? `log.debug("nextindex: ")`

Comment: No idea, but some debugging will probably help. We don't know the input though.